# Using sqlite3.exec() from CppSqlite3U

Tags: c++, sql, database, sqlite

How can [CppSQlite3U](https://github.com/SunDrop/CppSQLite3U) be used to execute queries in a similar way to [sqlite3_exec()](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html). The purpose of my question is to use CppSQLite3U in one hand but to take advantage of the callback mechanism sqlite3.exec() has?

Comment: See also http://naughter.com/sqlitewrappers.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it will help you. It is good sample for your case

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6343/CppSQLite-C-Wrapper-for-SQLite

Comment: Thanks Michael Haephrati